# SQL Query concatenation performance boost

Tags: sql, performance, where-clause

I have a class (that reflects a db row) that has more than 200 instances created within the codes bootstrap. Each one has a single `SELECT` query with the only condition being `WHERE 'tblA'.'AID' = #`, but I was thinking of creating a single query, that would parse 200 WHERE clauses connected by `OR` logic, then from the result, 200 objects are created with the data already found, so there is only 1 query.

I am implementing this on a test server at the moment, but I was wondering if this was a bad step for efficiency, and at what time it would be better to do 2 sets of queries, taking care of half the clauses each (or how ever many more need to be made)?

**Additional**, I am also writing a performance enhancer into it to replace something like

```
WHERE `tblA`.`AID` = 2 OR `tblA`.`AID` = 3 OR `tblA`.`AID` = 5 OR `tblA`.`AID` = 6 OR `tblA`.`AID` = 7
```

with

```
WHERE (`tblA`.`AID` >= 2 AND `tblA`.`AID` <= 3) OR (`tblA`.`AID` >= 5 AND `tblA`.`AID` <= 7)
```

or even

```
WHERE `tblA`.`AID` >= 2 AND `tblA`.`AID` <= 7 AND `tblA`.`AID` <> 4
```

Comment: Please state what RDBMS implementation you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a discrete list, then just use `in` . . .

```
where AID in (2, 3, 5, 6, 7, . . .)
```

And let the SQL engine worry about the optimization.

The biggest hit is likely to be the time to parse the query and sending a large query to the engine.  If your list gets really long, then consider putting the list in a temporary table, building an index on the table, and doing a join.

You don't specify what database you are using, but this advice is pretty database-agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

You still haven't specified DBMS.

For SQL Server this might be modestly worthwhile (though you may well want to consider joining on a table valued parameter or similar rather than having a lengthy `IN` list anyway).

SQL Server will do separate individual seeks rather than collapse them into contiguous ranges. This is covered thoroughly in the article [When is a Seek not a Seek?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/16/when-is-a-seek-not-a-seek.aspx) but some examples below.

```
CREATE TABLE T (X int PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO T 
SELECT TOP 1000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
FROM master..spt_values v1, master..spt_values v2

SET STATISTICS IO ON;

SELECT *
FROM   T
WHERE   X IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,
              11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
              21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
              31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,
              41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,
              51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,
              61,62,63,64)
```

> Table 'T'. Scan count 64, logical reads 192

```
SELECT *
FROM   T
WHERE   X BETWEEN 1 AND 64
```

> Table 'T'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3

As mentioned in the comments on the article for greater than 64 values you will get a slightly different plan that adds a table of constants and a nested loops join into the mix.